# How to fetch data as a .zip using Cx_Oracle?

Tags: python, sql, oracle, compression, cx-oracle

I would like to fetch the data but receiving a .zip with all the data instead of a list of tuples of data. That is, making the specified query, then database server compresses the result data as .zip and then sends this .zip to client.
By doing this I expect to reduce time spent on sending data by a lot, because there are lots of repeated fields.

I know [Advanced Data compression](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/advancednetworkcompression-2141325.pdf) exists in Oracle, however I am not able to achieve this using Cx_Oracle.

Any help/ workaround is appreciated.

Comment: Oracle cannot natively create a zip file. You will have to do that in the application/client: i.e. in python.

Comment: @pmdba Well, I would like to do it in the server, to make data transfer faster. Are you sure there is not any way of doing this? Or, any workaround?

Comment: The only way to compress data in transit is with the Advanced Compression Option. This would compress the network packets on the wire but not produce a zip file. It can compress native Oracle days files of various types at rest, but does not create zip files of exported data. Advanced Compression is an extra cost, separately licensed feature of Oracle and you would need to talk to Oracle Sales if you don't already have it.

Comment: I have Advanced Compression, how can I enable it using Cx_Oracle? I have searching for documentation, but there isn't any parameter to specify this.

Comment: This sounds like a question asked before.  And my answer then was to use SQL and PL/SQL to construct a minimal data set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Advanced Network Compression can be enabled as described here, using sqlnet.ora and/or tnsnames.ora:

- https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/initialization.html#optnetfiles
- https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/advancednetworkcompression-2141325.pdf

Comment: Tried (DESCRIPTION= (COMPRESSION=on) (COMPRESSION_LEVELS=(LEVEL=low)... with levels low and hight for 8 million observations. Both cases taked more time than without compression. Oracle Compression doesn't work properly and it's definetly not worth the money.

Comment: What it probably means is that you're just not dealing with a large enough data set to make the CPU overhead of the compression worth it, or that you don't have enough CPU resources available on either the server or the client. Compression isn't a cure-all - it only adds benefit in specific use cases when you can recover more resource overhead from the network latency than you're spending on the increased CPU.

Comment: Well, I guess your are right, but isn't 8 million rows enough? Database Server is not a problem... very powerful machine. When I compress the retrieved data using 7-zip zip deflated reduce the size by 80 %....

Comment: I don't think Oracle compression is working properly...

Comment: You're talking about two different kinds of compression. Network compression isn't doing deduplication like file compression; it is compressing the network packets as they stream. Also, the CPU resources of your client (not just the server) will play a factor in the efficiency of the network compression, as you decompress the stream on the receiving end.

Comment: Oh, that's the reason. Thank you very much for you knowledge!. There is not any type of deduplicaton compression in the server side? It would be game changing!

Comment: You would have to construct the entire dataset first, and transmit as a file, not as part of a user session. DB applications and clients don't operate that way. Most apps want first rows of data as quickly as possible to present to the user, then cache the rest of the results in the background and allow the user to page through them. No one wants to wait for the entire result set to be constructed, compressed, transmitted, decompressed, and then placed into memory before seeing a single row. That would require way more CPU and disk I/O and take much longer than streaming directly to memory.

Comment: Munge the data to BLOB and use PL/SQL's UTL_COMPRESS ?  Write an [external procedure](https://www.oracle.com/pls/topic/lookup?ctx=dblatest&id=GUID-456B8988-6418-45C7-86EF-77EA0BE0BCEC) ? Or use SQL & PL/SQL to deduplicate the data?  Or let Oracle DB decide what is the optimal internal format?  With any, tune the application arraysize & prefetchsize.  And tune the [net SDU and other buffer sizes](https://static.rainfocus.com/oracle/oow19/sess/1553616880266001WLIh/PF/OOW19_Net_CON4641_1569022126580001esUl.pdf)?